# Adding entities to Stanford NLP NER Classifier

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have a very simple method to extract Names, Organisations and Locations from a string. I am using the .NET Nuget Libraries for Stanford NLP. It looks like this.

```
CRFClassifier Classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(StanfordNLPConfig.NER.ClassifierModel);

        List<IndexViewModel> ivms = new List<IndexViewModel>();

        try
        {
            foreach (List sentence in Classifier.classify(content).toArray())
            {
                NLPTranslator translator = new NLPTranslator();
                ivms.AddRange(translator.NERTranslate(sentence));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            // Error silently
        }

        return ivms;
```

The model is the 3class jar file it came with - english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz.

This is working really well for me, but would I'd like to do is interface with the model to be able to add in my own entities should I need to, this seems very American Centric and I'd like to be able to put my own UK companies, locations etc.

Is there any way I can just add in these entities as I have been reading about training it but that you possibly can't extend the model, if this is the case can I combine Classifiers and run it through a UK one/US one etc. If that's possible, how can I actually make my own Classifier as I would like to make these in .NET if possible.

Comment: I currently have the same issue, If I am able to find out how to do this I'll post here, I would ask that if you find out how before me to answer your own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the way the model works you'll need to provide training data and train your own model. For licensing reasons Stanford doesn't distribute the data the public models are trained on, but you can use the same features.

You can read about how to train a model [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a), though unfortunately the first sentence of the instructions is this:

> The documentation for training your own classifier is somewhere between bad and non-existent.

If this is your first time working with a CRF there will many things to learn but it is manageable. It may be helpful to look at documentation for other packages such as [CRFSuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) and [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) - they generally all use basically the same training data format and are similar in many ways.

Also note that the existing models cannot be extended by training them just on new input, the system just isn't set up that way.